# Book references about continued fractions

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, math-history, continued-fractions

I'm searching for one or more books about continued fractions which covers these aspects:

1. An introductory level book about continued fractions.
2. A divulgative book about continued fractions with some historical background on how and when continued fractions were discovered. (These can be two books, each covering one of the two aspects.)
3. A book (article or something related) about didactic with continued fractions.

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: I haven't read it yet, so I can't tell if it's suitable, but Jonathan Borwein et al., *Neverending Fractions: An Introduction To Continued Fractions* (Cambridge University Press 2014) is probably worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Continued Fractions, by C. D. Olds](https://bookstore.ams.org/nml-9) was my first book on the topic (in high school, I think?), and I was hooked.

Comment: Also the first book I saw on the topic, being one of a handful of the earliest New Mathematical Library books our school library had (early to mid 1970s). Maybe add to your answer what is probably the standard historical reference on the topic -- [**History of Continued Fractions and Padé Approximants**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/3540152865) by Claude Brezinski (1991).

Answer (score 3):

I enjoyed *Continued Fractions* by A. Ya. Khinchin. It's very short and clear.

Part I covers the elementary results that everyone ought to know.

Part III is about the measure theory of continued fractions: For example, pick a number at random from an interval; what's the probability that its CF expansion contains a 3 somewhere? This theory leads to the surprising result that the geometric mean of the partial denominators has [the same value, about $2.6854$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_constant), for nearly all numbers.

Inexpensive copies are widely available.  [The current Dover edition costs US$8.95](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486696308.html).